# Hidden field validation message

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, symfony-3.3

In my form, I have an address and 2 hidden fields : lat and lng.
When the user click on the button 'locate' (not part of the form), with the address filled, I calculate coordinates and fill the hidden fields lat and lng.

If those fields are not filled, I do have an error (as they are mandatory), but as they are hidden, the error is not attached to any field (I only see the error on the debug bar of Symfony).

I tried using `$context->buildViolation()->atPath` to attach the message to the Address entity (and not the lat or lng attributes) but I don't know if I can attach the error to the parent form... (it does not seem to work...)

If I attach the error to an other field of the Address entity, I do see the error message, but it is not logical (as the error is not on these fields).

How can I show the error message above the adresses' fields ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem : as I managed each field using `form_row(form.myfield)`, I haven't the `form_row(form)` so neither `form_errors(form)`.

The errors are well shown if I add `form_errors(form)`